# TSServer false positive inside async jest tests

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library, react-context

I'm trying to make a simple assynchronous test which calls a function that interacts with ContextAPI and useState methods

Here is the snippet:

```
  it('should append submited value to feed', async () => {
    const input = FakeElement.getByTestId('input') as HTMLInputElement
    fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: 'testing' } })
    expect(input.value).toBe('testing')

    await feedSubmitHandler(Ev, Ref, Feed, SetFeed)
    expect(Feed.messages).toContain('testing')
  })
```

Just to be clear:
feedSubmitHandler is a function of type (ev: Event, ref: React.Ref, Feed: Object, setFeed: setStateAction) => void

This test works perfectly, but only with async await, which is expected.
The thing is that TSServer is hightlighting the `await feedSubmitHandler...` line telling me "await has no effect on this type of expression"

Why is that?
How to properly set it up so that it doesn't complain?

So to wrap up. The whole issue is about some missconfiguration i'm having with Jest, Typescript and TSServer. I wan't it to recognize that it shouldn't complain about i'm 'awaiting' for a function that returns void inside this test scenario.

I thought about maybe setting another tsconfig.test.json file for tests only but i'm not sure how to elegantly do that.

Comment: *TSServer is hightlighting* - it's unclear what you talk about. Is it IDE error or what? It sounds like you ran TSServer yourself which is rarely a case. *but only with async await, which is expected* - why is this expected? The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , there's no feedSubmitHandler.

Comment: Sorry. I'm inside neovim with coc-nvim and coc-tsserver extension. Which is basically a VSCode enviroment.
I edited my question to further clarify it

Comment: If there's an exact error that mentions TSServer, a quote or a screenshote would give more context. As for the function, it doesn't return a promise so it's semantically incorrect to `await` it, this is what the message talks about. If it's asynchronous and needs some time to work, `await` a promise that it involves, or RTL assertion, or flush-promises.

Comment: Yes the only error is those squigly lines i get under this line of code. But the thing is, why does it complain if it is NECESSARY to make the test work? That's the issue i'm having with it.

Comment: The question doesn't explain why it's necessary. It complains because it's a wrong thing to do. In your case I suppose that it's a hack that caused it to work, not a legit solution. Please, provide MCVE that shows what happens in your test.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you figure out a solution? I can't find anything in typescript's docs to warrant another `tsconfig` file either.